# CXF WSS4J Interceptor documentation/manual

Tags: cxf, wss4j

I have spent a fair amount of time finding tutorials and implementing signatures and encryption on a catalog of Web Services. Now i need to extend that functionality to allow each user to have their own signature and encryption keys.

For that reason i started to look around for some actual documentation of how to use the WSS4J Interceptors, but i can't for the life of me find anything. The best i have been able to find is the SecurityConstants class description in http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/ API.

So my question is: Does anyone know where i can find some actual documentation type writings about the interceptor classes. Specifically:
What can go into the object map in the interceptor constructors?
How should these objects be configured?

I don't mind a lot of reading, in fact i prefer it at this point. There are a million blogs and tutorials that give basic implementation advice, but what i need is a little bit of actual documentation. Anyone?

If nothing else, i will even be satisfied with half-baked javadoc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this URL that explains about Interceptors mechanism. Its good one.

https://sites.google.com/site/ddmwsst/ws-security-impl

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would recommend NOT using the WSS4J interceptors directly in CXF at this point.  Instead, define a WS-Security policy fragment that will accurately describe the security requirements and attach that in the WSDL.   Then add the appropriate properties (described http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html ) for the additional information the policy runtime will need.

The WS-Security Policy stuff is completely standards based and would be supported by all the various runtimes.  The security requirement become part of the contract (WSDL) which is also important.

Comment: "However, the WS-SecurityPolicy fragment does not include "everything" that is required for a runtime ... It does not describe things such as locations of key stores, user names and passwords, etc... Those need to be configured in at runtime to augment the WS-SecurityPolicy fragment." This is a relief for me, since my primary concern was that i needed to specify keys at runtime, and the interceptors did not seems to agree. But i will have to restate my question then. Where to find information? I see a nice long doc about the security policy in general, but no javaside documentation?